# What is the difference between @var [type] <variableName> and $variableName = <value> in magento 2 PHTML files

Tags: php, e-commerce, magento2

I am new to PHP and Magento2. I was reading some sample code in a PHTML file and came across this style of declaring a variable

```php
<?php
    /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title $title */
?>
```

And I could use the `$title` variable as if I had declared and made it an instance of the `Title` class.

Right below that, there was another piece like so:

```php
<?php
    $text = $title->getPageTitle();
?>
```

What is the difference between the two styles of declaration?

Importantly, why doesn't Magento2 complain about the undeclared variable `$title` in this case?

**EDIT**

It was not

```php
<?php
    /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title $title */
?>
```

Instead it is written as

```php
<?php
    /** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title $block */
?>
```

The question is still the same, as to how can `$block` be used without actually declaring it

Comment: `/** @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title $title */` is just a comment. Most IDE 
 use this as documentation. It tell your IDE of which type `$title` is. `$text = $title->getPageTitle();`: `$title` (being of type `\Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title`) calls its method `getPageTitle()` and stores it in `$text`. Your code would also perfectly function without the comment, its just nice to have the support of an IDE.

Comment: But the `$title` is not declared before. The only place of its declaration is the in the comments. That's the part I am confused about. How can that declaration work, if it's inside phpdoc

Comment: @DefinitelynotRafal I have made an edit to the question, please can you tell me the answer in that context, that how can `$block` be used without declaring it

Comment: Magento (as many other frameworks) uses the [MVC pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). **Once again the part you have changed is just a comment, it does absolutely nothing to the logic of the script/application, its just a comment.** The fact that $title is being initialized is because of the mvc and how it works. The view (the file you get those codes from) recieves those variables already initialized by the executing controller. You can try to `echo $block` but it will achieve nothing. Because its not initialized like `$title`.

Comment: That explains it...thanks!